# Android - HelloWorld app in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

well i am completely new in making Android application.I m not able to remove errors in the source code . here it is , source code -

**"its not able to resolve R as a variable "**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Clea build your project. And see if your layout file contains errors

Comment: What is R and what is it used for?

Comment: there may be some thing wrong in your resources.If cleaning the project does not help.

Comment: May be you are missing a class called 'R'?

Comment: Did you made a correct reference to app compact lib ??

Comment: @Guilmon, hemanth: those "in the know" know [what `R` is](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the R file is missing, here are several solutions:

1. Select the project, click Project - Clean, clean up projects;
2. Select the project, right-select Android Tools - Fix Project Properties;
3. Select the project, right-select Properties - Android, select the appropriate version, and click OK;

Thus R files will be re-generated.

Comment: i did tht but its not helping

Answer (score 0):

Look at your imports. check if this line exists:

```
import android.R;
```

If present, remove it, so that your project will resolve R not with the default Android Resources class, and import R with your package name

Answer (score 0):

1. Try Clean & build. There is no problem with your java file.
2. If it still shows the error, Check out layout/activity_main.xml . Did you  write something there which is not syntactically correct?

3.If you didn't change anything there, I suggest you to restart eclipse & clean-build again. Make sure yuor anot importing android's R file , you will need to import your project's R file.
 There should not be any other cause.

Answer (score 0):

Check your **AndroidManifest.xml** file it may contains some erroer by which your R.java not genrated.

or 
Check with new **eclipes**

and in Your activity.java file Press CTRL + SHIFT + O

Answer (score 0):

Its your IDE problem, eclipse right... ? sometime eclipse can't generate R.java,

Im suggest you to take course from here

https://www.udacity.com/course/ud853

and if you have using Eclipse as IDE, try to change into AndroidStudio, if you have facing some problem while using AndroidStudio join Community on Gplus here https://plus.google.com/communities/114791428968349268860

Cheers

Comment: yes i m using eclipse. so i really cant do anything about it ?

Comment: try restarting your Eclipse, than rebuild or clean project,, Project > Clean

and check under folder res/ , find some error in there, R.java no generated is because there is something wrong under folder res/

and remember R in android has two R from android and R from your project :) and check your console windows too, maybe there is some useful information in there